# What is the value of $\arctan(y/x)$ for $y=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

What is the value of $\arctan(y/x)$ for $y=0$?

Must it depend on the value of $x$?

I seem to be getting
$$\arctan(y/x) = \begin{cases}
0, x > 0 \\
\pi, x < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
if I restrict my arctangent on $(-\pi, \pi]$.  Is this correct?

**Added September 16 2017**

Per this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), the range of the usual principal value of $\arctan z$ is indeed in $(-{\pi/2},{\pi/2})$.  Hence, indeed $\arctan(y/x) = 0$ when $y = 0$.

Comment: As long as $x\neq 0$ why should it matter what $x$ is? $0/x=0$ regardless

Comment: We actually typically only consider $\arctan(x)\in\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Maybe this arises in the context of converting from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, in which case it does matter.

Comment: @kimchilover, yes that is exactly the context of my question.  To the downvoter, could you kindly explain your vote?

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your question.  You want to solve $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ and the naive recipe $\theta =\arctan y/x$ is not exactly correct in all cases.

Comment: Now that I have mentioned it, converting from Cartesian to polar coordinates is not really what I'm exactly doing.  I am just trying to find the value of $\arctan(y/x)$ when $x < 0$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Ah. As above $\arctan(x) \in \left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$, hence you can't simply apply arctan in all cases. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote, but when $\theta = \arctan(x) \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, $x > 0$.  So that reasoning does not apply in my case.

Comment: corrected my answer

Comment: @GeorgeCoote, gladly accepting your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking...

$$\arctan\left(\frac 0 x\right) = \arctan(0) = 0$$

For all $x \neq 0$

**Edit** in the case of polar coords, complex numbers, etc...

You are correct that, $x \in \mathbb R$,

$$\arg(x+0i) = \begin{cases} \arctan(0), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\ge 0 \\ \arctan(0)+\pi, 
 \ \ x<0\end{cases}$$
$$\arg(x+0i) = \begin{cases} 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \ge 0 \\ \pi, 
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x<0\end{cases}$$

Remember that $\arctan$ remains single-valued under the typical interpretation. (though you can redefine it as a multifunction of some sorts)

To verify, you can observe that

$$\exp(0) = i\sin 0 + \cos 0 = 1$$
$$\exp(i\pi) = i\sin \pi + \cos \pi = -1$$